# Se pueden dejar fijo el tamaño de la fila en una tabla con bootstrap 5 y react

Tags: html, bootstrap, reactjs

Me he encontrado en un dilema.
al mostrar la información de un monitoreo de calidad en la columna observaciones se desborda el tamaño de fila.
Existe alguna manera de dejar fijo el tamaño de la columna y que si el usuario quiera ver mas le aparesca un scroll dentro de la celda para que lo pueda leer.
Mas que todo es presentación porque generalmente lo que hacen es descargarlo en un excel.
Adjunto codigo:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover  table-striped table-bordered ml-4 ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Observacion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        {record.map((name) =>
        <tr>
            <td>{name.first_name}</td>
            <td>{name.last_name}</td>
            <td>{name.email}</td>
            <td>{name.phone}</td>
            <td>{name.obs}</td>
        </tr>
        )}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Saludos...

Answer (score 1):

tuve que realizar una constante y luego aplicar el estilo a la columna:

```
const styleRow = {
    "display": "block",
    "overflow-y": "scroll",
    "max-height": "160px"
}
```

Y en la tabla:

```
<td style={styleRow}>{name.obs}</td>
```

Gracias